# CCXT.load_markets() function running fail in EC2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, ccxt

I have a problem running ccxt.load_markets() function in EC2 server
but I check running is OK in local PC enviroment.
Please me help for solution

Code and Error msg is as below.

python version : 3.7.15
CCXT version : 2.2.95

```
import ccxt
import time

b= ccxt.binance()

print(b.milliseconds())
print(b.nonce())
print(b.load_markets())
```

---

1671012133696
1671012133696
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 621, in fetch
response.raise_for_status()
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 451 Client Error:  for url: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 15, in 
print(b.load_markets())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 1448, in load_markets
markets = self.fetch_markets(params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/binance.py", line 1613, in fetch_markets
response = getattr(self, method)(query)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 501, in inner
return entry(_self, **inner_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/binance.py", line 5854, in request
response = self.fetch2(path, api, method, params, headers, body, config, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 2782, in fetch2
return self.fetch(request['url'], request['method'], request['headers'], request['body'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 639, in fetch
self.handle_http_status_code(http_status_code, http_status_text, url, method, http_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 1741, in handle_http_status_code
raise ErrorClass(self.id + ' ' + method + ' ' + url + ' ' + codeAsString + ' ' + reason + ' ' + body)
ccxt.base.errors.ExchangeNotAvailable: binance GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo 451  {
"code": 0,
"msg": "Service unavailable from a restricted location according to 'b. Eligibility' in https://www.binance.com/en/terms. Please contact customer service if you believe you received this message in error."
}

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because the request to binance server is being sent from a restricted location. Binance blacklists some locations due to policies and regulation. Since you are running on aws EC2 instance, it is most likely that your virtual server is located in a restricted location. Using VPN is also risky since binance server are able to identify most of them. The solution would be to rent a virtual server that exists from binance legible locations.